# How to run python unittests for multiple implementations in one go

Tags: python, unit-testing, testing

I'm having trouble figuring out the proper way of using pythons unittest framework

I currently have 3 different implementations for a data structure class and unittests to test various things in the class as follows:

```
import fooHorse
import fooSnake
import fooMoose
import unittest

foo = fooHorse.foo()
#foo = fooSnake.foo()
#foo = fooMoose.foo()

class testFoo(unittest.TestCase):
    def testSomething(self):
        foo.do_something()
    ...
    def testSomethingelse(self):
        ...
    # etc

if __name__ == "__main__":
    unittest.main()
```

How do I refactor the code so that all the tests are run for `fooSnake.foo`, `fooMoose.foo` and `fooHorse.foo`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just factor all the testing into a function and call it from the three tests :

```
class testFoo(unittest.TestCase):
    def _doTest(self, foo):
         foo.do_something()
         # ...

    def testFoorHorse(self):
        foo = fooHorse.foo()
        self._doTest(foo)
    # and so on.
```

I wouldn't try to do anything more clever so that the test logic stays simple enought to be obviously bug-free.

Answer (score 0):

I think it is better to keep the testing code inside the classes under test (so, inside the `fooHorse` classes and such). I can't really tell from the code segment, so maybe you are already doing that. Then to combine multiple tests to be run at the same time, or selecting a few of them, you could create a separate testing class that creates a test suite. In there, the individual unittests can be assigned. See the [python docs](http://docs.python.org/library/unittest.html#grouping-tests) for details on this.